# Error INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT when trading pancake

Tags: solidity, uniswap, pancakeswap, uniswapv3

A newly created token contract is normally traded on the testnet,
Published to the main network, this error occurs when selling coins INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT;
https://pancakeswap.finance/swap?outputCurrency=BNB&inputCurrency=0x78A390428db88C3AcA19bAaC7031C6e9756FAC36

Excuse me, please help me check what is the problem! Thank you!!!

Comment: If from a token did you approve the token for trade with the router?
If swapping from native coin are you passing a msg.value?

Do you have a hash of the failed swap?

Comment: Can you provide the contract source code?